# PHP: Get name of directories which doesn't contain file “input…”?

Tags: php, directory

Please give me a solution for get name of directories which doesn't contain file “input…” using php. My folder structure is like this:

```
Main Dir
  namedirectory.php
  Dir1
    File1
    input_1.txt
    File
  Dir2
    File5
    File6
  Dir3
    File1
    input_2.txt
  Dir4
    File1
    File2
  Dir5
    File1
    File2
```

Because Dir1 and Dir3 has "input.." files, so it will get name=dir2,dir4,dir5. I have code but it doesn't work. Please help me fix it !

```
<?php
$dir ='/directory';
while($dirs = glob($dir . '/*', GLOB_ONLYDIR)) {
  $dir .= '/*';
  if(!$d) {
     $d=$dirs;
   } else {
      $d=array_merge($d,$dirs);     
   }

  foreach ($d as $d) {

     if ($handle = opendir($d)) {
        while ($entry = readdir($handle)) {
           if (strpos($entry, "input") === FALSE) {
               echo $d;
               break;
           }
        }
      closedir($handle);
     }
  }

}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use tripple = because PHP will cast `false` to 0 which will be true.

Change:

```
if (strpos($entry, "input") == FALSE) {
```

Into

```
if (strpos($entry, "input") === FALSE) {
```

**EDIT**

```
$dir ='/directory';
while($dirs = glob($dir . '/*', GLOB_ONLYDIR)) {
  $dir .= '/*';
  if(!$d) {
     $d=$dirs;
   } else {
      $d=array_merge($d,$dirs);     
   }

  foreach ($d as $d) {

     if ($handle = opendir($d)) {
        $showDirectory = true;
        while ($entry = readdir($handle)) {
           if (strpos($entry, "input") !== FALSE) {
                $showDirectory = false;
                break;
           }
        }
        if($showDirectory)
        {
            echo $d;
        }
      closedir($handle);
     }
  }

}
```

Comment: I noticed that you also missing an `}` character at the end of the PHP. You don't close the `while` loop.

Comment: yes, it doesn't show output. I added } but it show nothing when I run

Comment: yes, I use wrong directory :D. However, I still don't show what I want

Comment: Although some directory have file input...txt but it still show. I don't want to show directory which has file input...txt. How to do that ?

Comment: Edited my aswer, can you try that? Only with the right directory ;)

Comment: Hello, I tried but it still show directory which has input...txt

Comment: Hmm changed `=== TRUE` to `!== FALSE`. Can you try it?